# Linking firebase password user with facebook user

Tags: swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have successfully implemented email and Facebook login authentication using Firebase. I would now like to allow email users to link their account with Facebook.

I have the following code for this:

```
let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

 if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
     user.link(with: credential, completion: { user, error in
         // 
     })
 }
```

The linking works, but the user returned has no displayName nor photoUrl. Either the user returned in the completion block or when accessing the user via `Auth.auth().currentUser`.

The user does have a displayName and photoUrl though when authenticating directly with Facebook. Not sure why these properties are nil when linking an account. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are first signing up the user with email/password and then linking Facebook to their account. The Firebase Auth backend will not copy the Facebook profile data to the top level `displayName` and `photoURL`.
However, the solution for this is very easy, you can after linking, copy the Facebook displayName and photoURL from the Facebook `currentUser.providerData[indexOfFacebook]` and use `currentUser.createProfileChangeRequest()` to update the `displayName` and `photoURL` on currentUser.